# About the 1.14.0 Minecraft update

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I found some bees and was bringing them to my base to give them their new home in a makeshift beehive, but before I got all the way there I had to 1st deal with a skeleton, a moment after thag the bees suddenly stopped following me and acted like the flower I was holding had no effect, can someone please tell me what on earth is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lure-able animals temporarily ignore (like a following cooldown) you when you switch from holding an item that the mobs like, to a different item, and then switching back to it (I would guess that in this situation, you were holding a flower in your hand, switched to a sword to kill the skeleton, then switched back to the flower).

A few things could solve or prevent this problem:

1. During their following cooldown, try to follow them until they stop ignoring you and start to follow you again.
2. Use leads instead of flowers to transport bees around, as especially with bees it's much easier to use a lead as unlike other lead-able animals, they can fly meaning that they're less likely to get stuck behind blocks and break the lead.
3. Re-log/exit the world and rejoin, and it might overwrite it's following cooldown, or reduce the time the cooldown affects the mob.
4. This currently wouldn't be possible on Bedrock Edition, but on Java Edition you could equipt the item needed to lure the specific animal mob in your off-hand so you can hold both a flower and another item(like a sword, map, or food) at the same time.